# Kotlin project shows "Unresolved Reference" errors after renaming the package in Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to change the package name of an open source Kotlin project to a different one so that I can upload it to Google Play. The code after download runs okay, builds and runs on both emulator and physical phone.

I tried to change the project name by using the refactor but after that the build sequence throws unresolved reference errors on a number of classes.

[image]

I'm sure of these:

- The errors are definitely related to the name changing process
- Invalidate Chaches & Restart IDE won't help
- Manually Find & Replace strings won't make a difference
- There's no trace of old name space (com.xxx.xxx) in any files.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you go to any activity of yours and check what it is showing at the top of the code? check package name of DeckList,TipStateDb , etc

Comment: So, I fixed the issue and this is what I did: 1) downloaded a fresh copy of the code. 2) Find & Replace original namespace with the new one through Edit > Find > Replace in Files 3) Manually refactor folder names in "app" folder 4) Build.